# What's the difference between the numerous methods to get input from the user?

Tags: java

Take for example the following basic program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        char userInput;
        String convertString;

        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Here are your choices:");
            System.out.println("A. \nB. \nC. \nD.");

            Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
            convertString = kbd.next();
            userInput = convertString.charAt(0);

            switch(userInput)
            {
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("You have chosen A!");
                break;
            case 'B':
                System.out.println("You have chosen B!");
                break;
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("You have chosen C!");
                break;
            case 'D':
                System.out.println("You have chosen D! This program will now terminate.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry, you have to make a selection.");
            }
        } while (userInput > 'D');

    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine.
However, if instead of using the *Scanner* version, I use the *System.in.read()* version, my program will loop 3 times before allowing me to make a selection.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Since I come from a C/C++ background, I'm assuming it's because there's the character *\n* 'left over' in the input stream, and when the program loops without allowing me to type my desired input, it's 'clearing' the stream. But if this is true, why is it looping 3 times instead of just once (since to clear *\n* you only need to get another left-over character from the input stream)?

And finally, which method is best/more commonly used?

Thanks!

Comment: System.in based methods are depreciated, don't use it, it was bad, they realised it was bad, they gave us Scanner, we were happy

Comment: System.in.read() reads a SINGLE byte from the input stream. Try wrapping it in an InputStreamReader and reading a whole line.

Comment: @RichardTingle: `System.in` is not deprecated, and it's not bad either, it's just not the right tool for this job. They realized that the right tool was missing, and that's why `Scanner` was added.

Comment: @RichardTingle You sure about that? I'm pretty sure every wrapper for an input stream will have to use `InputStream.read` at some point.

Comment: Possibly an exaggeration, its direct usage is no longer usual

Comment: So for this particular example, where I need the user to enter a menu character, would using Scanner the way I currently have it set up be best?

Comment: @user2776780 Scanner is just a wrapper for an input stream to simply/add functionality. So yes, using a scanner in your case is perfectly acceptable. A decent way to choose a wrapper (ie scanner, bufferedreader) is use whichever gets the job done in the least amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

The program loops three times when you use `System.in.read()` because on Windows the line separator is two characters: carriage return followed by line feed, or `"\r\n"`.

On Unix systems (Mac OS X, Linux, Solaris, ...) the line separator is a single line feed `\n`.

You can overcome this issue by wrapping `System.in` in a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and reading entire lines, or even better, use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) classes, or best of all according to some people, use a graphical user interface.

An example of using the old method:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = in.readLine();
```

An example of using the `Console` class:

```
Console con = System.console();
String line = con.readLine();
```

Comment: Using an InputStreamReader should be just as good right? The data is buffered by the console before sent to the java program

Comment: The `InputStreamReader` class doesn't have a `readLine` method, but it is needed as an intermediate step to create a BufferedReader.

Comment: For some reason I thought InputStreamReader could read lines. Oh well

Answer (score 0):

`System.in` is an `InputStream`, which is a pretty low-level stream class akin to the `std::streambuf` in C++ or `fread` in C. It lets you read single bytes and fixed size byte arrays. To do something useful with it, you should wrap it in a `BufferedReader`, which offers a `readLine()` method.